# Using SASS, need to output CSS to different directory

Tags: css, sass, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I jumped into SASS tonight and I'm using Sublime Text 2 with SASS Build and SublimeOnSaveBuild. After much searching, I still cannot find how to specify a different output directory. I basically have a CSS/ directory and a SCSS/ directory which contains all of my SASS files. I want to output to ../CSS. I think it involves modifying the Package Setting file in Sublime. Here is the default preferences file:

{
    "filename_filter": "\.(css|js|sass|less|scss)$",
    "build_on_save": 1
}

I believe the "build" or "output" path goes there but I'm just not sure. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

The answer is to change the settings for SASS Build, rather than SublimeOnSaveBuild. SASS Build creates a "Build System" for SASS and SASS Minified. You can go to Preferences -> Browse Packages, open the SASS Build folder, and then edit the two files ending with *-build*.

```
"cmd": ["sass", "--update", "$file:${file_path}/${file_base_name}.css", "--stop-on-error", "--no-cache"],
```

You can edit the file path there (there isn't a way to do per project yet it seems):

```
"cmd": ["sass", "--update", "$file:${file_path}/../css/${file_base_name}.css", "--stop-on-error", "--no-cache"],
```

Now, how to get them to stop building partials...that's the separate issue that I'm currently trying to find the best way to resolve. EDIT: [Stopped it from building partials. Posted a blog about it here.](http://www.joshuawinn.com/ignore-sass-and-less-partials-starting-with-underscore-when-using-sublimeonsavebuild/)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this does not directly answer your question, but I'd like to try.

In my SASS installation (with Compass, however), I have config.rb in my project. In there you can actually specify where the compiled CSS file go.

```
...
css_dir = "css"
...
```

If you are not using [Compass](http://compass-style.org/), my humble suggestion is to have a look at it. It is sort of an extension to SASS (much like jQuery to javascript)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I came across that file while I was searching around but I realized it was exclusively for Compass. If I can't resolve the Sublime packages in a few days then I will probably just purchase Compass. Currently I copy my SCSS files to my CSS directory and it builds in place but I would prefer to have some control over where it outputs. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you need to purchase Compass, it is open-source. The good thing about Compass: as a package it allows you to control where it is outputted, much like what you needed. And `compass -watch` build automatically too.

Answer (score -1):

Install 'compass'. Create your next project in the terminal using compass (this is all documented) and the config.rb file will have the appropriate folders/directories and your sass/compass compiler will do everything automatically. You can either use compass watch in the terminal or a programme like LiveReload to do the work for you. In fact, use LiveReload. Honestly, you won't regret it!!!